# difference between uiscrollview and uiwebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

what is the difference between uiscorllview and uiwebview and how to find which one i should chose for my app

Comment: Kindly go through the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class name are not so clear?

What are your needs?

Here is definitions of both ;)

**UIScrollView**

> The UIScrollView class provides support for displaying content that is larger than the size of the application’s window. It enables users to scroll within that content by making swiping gestures, and to zoom in and back from portions of the content by making pinching gestures.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

**UIWebView**

> You use the UIWebView class to embed web content in your application. To do so, you simply create a UIWebView object, attach it to a window, and send it a request to load web content. You can also use this class to move back and forward in the history of webpages, and you can even set some web content properties programmatically.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

A `UIScrollView` allows you to render content larger than the size of the device's screen. You can scroll (obviously) and zoom the content (with some work).

The `UIWebView` can render HTML content, either from the web or from a local cache. It supports scrolling and zooming as well.